# Redirect an Expired Page

Tags: expire

For some reason i can't figure this one out. We have deals on our site that are set to expire on certain dates. These deals are sent out via email, so someone could click on a link after the deal has expired. If this happens, we would like to redirect them to the main deals page. My thought was to do this one of two ways:

1. If the entry is "closed" redirect to {segment_2}. The problem is that expired entries don't automatically change to "closed" status. How would i do this?
2. Use a conditional statement to either show page or redirect based on expiration date.. something like this:

   ```
   {exp:channel:entries
       status="open|featured|homepage|hidden"
       dynamic="no"
       limit="1"
       disable="member_data|trackbacks|categories"}

       {if expiration_date < current_time}
           SHOW DEAL
       {/if}

       {if expiration_date > current_time}
           REDIRECT TO {segment_2} 
       {/if}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
   ```

This isn't working either. I did a test with it to just show text based on the condition and both expired pages and live pages showed "SHOW DEAL". Obviously missing something here.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what happens when you output

```
Expires - {expiration_date} 

Current Time - {current_time}
```

Does that output look like two values you can use comparisons with? You could use Low Nice Date to convert times and dates (I think, check the [docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date/docs)), or perhaps have you looked at this addon?

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/auto-expire

It looks out of date, but might work still. Test it on a dev site first. And also look around devot-ee, there might be a newer version or one by a different author.

Comment: I've looked at this, but doesn't it just expire all entries in a certain channel after a certain amount of time? Each entry we have has a specific expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your conditional is inverted. Shouldn't it be?

```
{if expiration_date < current_time}
   {redirect='{segment_2}'}
{/if}
```

I can't test on an older version of eecms, but maybe the one you're using doesn't save the `expiration_date` as UNIX timestamp. In this case, try:

```
{if "{expiration_date format='%Y%m%d'}" < "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}
   {redirect='{segment_2}'}
{/if}
```

Comment: I think he wants people redirected to the deals page, not 404's. And yeah, I noticed that too, that his conditionals where reversed for the intended affect.

Comment: Correct. I do not want a 404 page. Sorry i typed the example wrong. I have used this code above to try to accomplish what i want and it just doesn't work. Seems simple enough. I checked the expiration date of a live deal and one that has expired and they both are accurate (one expired, one expires in Dec). Neither one redirects using the code above. If i reverse the less than to greater than It redirects both?

Comment: Wait! @ChrisBrown, which version of EECMS are using?

Comment: EE Version 2.9.0

Comment: @ChrisBrown, did my update helped?

Comment: Robson, Thanks for the reply. It does the same thing as before. Again, the strange thing is that it works opposite if i reverse the < to >. So a live page will redirect. The expired page still doesn't work with the correct code. I must have something else going on somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional was correct the whole time. I was missing the show_expired="yes" in the {exp:channel:entries. What was happening was that entry wasn't pulling at all so the conditional wasn't seeing anything. Once i added the show_expired it was able to see the expiration date to compare to. Thanks guys!